# d3.js Time arcs app

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I've looking to construct a curved timeline application.

[image]

In this example - I am trying to build a time chart which is represented by a curved line with ticks.

I may have these charts placed side by side in a concentric manner

- so the outer arc represents the start/end of duration for a film - with the time in divided up ticks.
- an inner chart runs parallel (next to the time chart) representing say chapters in the film.

_ the data could represent a user journey - like instead of duration its age. Instead of chapters its session data like logged on/off. Another ring inside could represent other interaction data against time - like dating information.

I've coded the charts in a way - the ticks could be represented inside or outside.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/235/

currently my data is hard coded as follows - what would be the advised way of transcribing this data as a timestamp - should this data be bridged to create the kind of data already being inputed?

```
            "data": [
                {
                    "segments": [
                        {
                            value: 5,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"
                        },
                        {
                            value: 100,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"                            
                        },
                        {
                            value: 5,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"                            
                        },
                        {
                            value: 100,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"
                        },
                        {
                            value: 5,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"
                        },
                        {
                            value: 100,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"                            
                        },
                        {
                            value: 5,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"                            
                        },
                        {
                            value: 100,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"
                        },
                        {
                            value: 5,
                            color: "#2c2c2e"                            
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

Comment: This version is now working off the difference between two dates. StartTime, EndTime. This may make more sense for session data - when a user logged in, when they logged off eg. May need to "make the gaps" up from inbetween the logged states in that case http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/308/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

*** LATEST CODE ***
Duration chart - jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/393
The chapter chart - jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/394

---

I've built on top of this now to handle dates and to also bridge data gaps - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/363/

So lets say this is being used to show session data or a person's event calendar.

```
{
   startTime: "1/3/2014 11:00:00",
   endTime: "2/3/2014 11:00:00"
},
{
   startTime: "6/3/2014 11:00:00",
   endTime: "7/3/2014 11:00:00"
},
{
   startTime: "8/3/2014 11:00:00",
   endTime: "9/3/2014 11:00:00"
}
```

So the three records - indicate the blips(indents). The troughs are calculated from previous start times, next end times - so the gaps are bridged. This could be handy in showing how active a user is - last time they logged in and for how long. I suppose the time scale data needs to represent minutes/seconds as opposed to days. Keen to look at any enhancements to this kind of chart. How to label it and where the labels should sit - how they get animated.

Comment: I've added a function to try and add the top labels - addLabel - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/387/ - this version mimics the duration chart in the example above